# How to set a content page gridview visibility in master page Visual basic

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to set  the visibility of various controls in my content page based off of a combobox in my master page being changed.  I'm already sending the text of the selection in this combobox to the content page to be used as it's parameter.  So what I need to do now is make my gridviews which are on my content page become visible after an item is selected in my masterpage.  This is in visual basic asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session. store the combobox value in the session and read it in each content page page load method.